# Dynamically generate templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to generate templatURL dynamically. I am using angularjs ui-routing

my routing function is:

```
}).state('error',{
    url: '/:locale/office-profile/',
    templateUrl: function(obj) {
        return 'partials/error-' + obj.locale + '.html';
    }
```

I read other stackoverflow answers where they have said to use such function. What I am trying to achieve is that obj.locale is dynamically populated. I tried to use $stateParams.locale since I thought that url has the locale already but that did not work either.

When I do console.log(obj) it prints **"Object: {locale: null}"** and hence it fails trying to load my template page.

Please advise on what should I do to achieve this. Thank You